# Triple nested C loop, integer iterator getting large before leaving inner loop

Tags: c

I have resolved this issue but I am not sure I understand where it came from. I believe it was because I declared par_x par_y and par_z incorrectly ( e.g.  float par_y = []). I resolved it by declaring it instead with a size and then calling initialize_particle.

For interest my code is a CFD one, I am adding to it some more functionality (passive particle tracking) and I am having problems with my triple nested loop.

```
int ii_ter, k_ter, j_ter

void initialize_particle(int d2x, int d2y, int d2z, float *par_x, float *par_y, float *par_z){
    for (ii_ter = 0; ii_ter < number_particles; ii_ter++){
        for (j_ter = 0; j_ter < number_particles; j_ter++){
            for (k_ter = 0; k_ter < number_particles; k_ter++){
            // number of particles in each direction, centred around  d2x d2y d2z
            // 
                printf("\nvalue ii_ter: %d, j_ter: %d, k_ter: %d\n", ii_ter, j_ter, k_ter);

                index_part = k_ter+j_ter*number_particles+ii_ter*number_particles*number_particles;

                printf("calc index %d \n", index_part);

                par_x[index_part] = 1 + d2x + k_ter - number_particles/(float)2;
                par_y[index_part] = 1 + d2x + j_ter - number_particles/(float)2;
                par_z[index_part] = 1 + d2x + ii_ter - number_particles/(float)2;

                printf("value of parx: %5.5f y: %5.5f z: %5.5f\n", par_x[index_part], par_y[index_part], par_z[index_part]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code is meant to go through and place a particle in a 3d cube, the k_ter for x axis y_ter for y axis and ii_ter for z axis.

index_part should go from 0 to number_particles^3

Except my output looks like

```
value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 0, k_ter: 0
calc index 0
value of parx: 34.50000 y: 34.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 0, k_ter: 1
calc index 1
value of parx: 35.50000 y: 34.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 0, k_ter: 2
calc index 2
value of parx: 36.50000 y: 34.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 1, k_ter: 0
calc index 3
value of parx: 34.50000 y: 35.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 1, k_ter: 1
calc index 4
value of parx: 35.50000 y: 35.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 1, k_ter: 2
calc index 5
value of parx: 36.50000 y: 35.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 2, k_ter: 0
calc index 6
value of parx: 34.50000 y: 36.50000 z: 34.50000

value ii_ter: 0, j_ter: 2, k_ter: 1
calc index 7
value of parx: 35.50000 y: 36.50000 z: 1108213794.50000

value ii_ter: 1108213760, j_ter: 2, k_ter: 2
calc index 1383989256
```

I have tried using a different variable and even a while loop. Even commenting out the par_x...par_z section of the code.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is "number_particles" initialized?

Comment: Smells like `ii_ter` is overwritten by something overflowing from your arrays.

Comment: What's the type of index_part? `index_part = k_ter+j_ter*number_particles+ii_ter*number_particles*number_particles;` could set it a 'very high' value.

Comment: There's a lot of fluff in your example code. A *minimum working example* would (a) help you to crystallize your ideas about where the problem might lie, and (b) help the community work out what's going on.

Comment: `int d2y` and `d2z` are being left unused, I think you might have been intending to use them with `par_y` and `par_z` close to the end.

Comment: There are too many global variables for comfort, and you don't show how they're initialized. The naming `j_ter`, `k_ter` and `ii_ter` is weirdly inconsistent. You should have printed `number_particles` (it appears to be 3).  You need to show where the parameter arrays are defined and the call to the function.

Comment: number_particles is at least 2, but for this example for us, you could have hard-coded it so we can see what's going on.  How are par_x, par_y, par_z declared?  Also, `index_part++;` would work the same as your assignment equation (if it was done at the end of the loop)

Comment: I can bet you have buffer overflow.

Comment: Show the declaration of the arrays passed as `par_x`, par_y`, etc.  They should be something like `float x[number_particles * number_particles * number_particles]; ... initialize_particle(..., x, y, z);`

Comment: Medinoc was right, my declaration of arrays was wrong and effected the iterator. I have fixed the code now by declaring the array size first.

Answer (score 0):

It's a late addition, but consistent with my comment — no global variables.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static
void initialize_particle(int d2x, int d2y, int d2z, int num, float *par_x, float *par_y, float *par_z)
{
    for (int i_ter = 0; i_ter < num; i_ter++)
    {
        for (int j_ter = 0; j_ter < num; j_ter++)
        {
            for (int k_ter = 0; k_ter < num; k_ter++)
            {
                printf("\nvalue i_ter: %d, j_ter: %d, k_ter: %d\n",
                       i_ter, j_ter, k_ter);
                int index_part = k_ter + j_ter * num + i_ter * num * num;
                printf("calc index %d \n", index_part);
                par_x[index_part] = 1 + d2x + k_ter - num / 2.0;
                par_y[index_part] = 1 + d2y + j_ter - num / 2.0;
                par_z[index_part] = 1 + d2z + i_ter - num / 2.0;
                printf("value of parx: %5.5f y: %5.5f z: %5.5f\n",
                       par_x[index_part], par_y[index_part], par_z[index_part]);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    float x[30];
    float y[30];
    float z[30];
    initialize_particle(35, 36, 37, 3, x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't crash.  An earlier version with 10 in place of 30 did crash!